# RuntimeError RMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rmagick

What i need to do that fix this error

```
This installation of RMagick was configured with ImageMagick 6.6.9 but ImageMagick 6.7.5-10 is in use.
```

app/uploaders/avatar_uploader.rb:2:in `include'
app/uploaders/avatar_uploader.rb:2:in`'
app/uploaders/avatar_uploader.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/models/user.rb:2:in`'
app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:1:in`'

This error occurred while loading the following files:
   RMagick
   RMagick2.so

Answer (score 0):

You probably updated ImageMagick on your system after you installed the gem, so the native gem extensions aren't matching up with your actual installed version.

You should just be able to reinstall the gem to get it to build against your newer ImageMagick 6.7.5-10:

```
gem install rmagick
```

Comment: now i have this libMagickCore.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/sergey/rubystack/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/RMagick2.so but this file is exist